# Why holes are better in storing both valley and pseudospin information?

Tags: momentum, metals, phonons

Recently I attended a class about transition-metal dichalcogenides (TMDC) and, during the lecture, the professor said that holes are better than electrons in storing both pseudospin and valley information. I know that it’s somehow related to transitions due to phonons and the fact that they are efficient in transferring momentum but not spin, but I don’t know much more. Could you help me? Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.nanolett.1c01538) by Kumar et al. from 2021 it is shown that the lifetime of holes is orders of magnitude longer than that of electrons. The paper explains that this is due to the differing energy landscapes seen by both species, meaning that it is much easier for electrons to be scattered. Excited electrons "live" in the conduction band which is only spin-orbit split slightly, while holes "live" in the conduction band which is spin-orbit split much more.

It could be in this sense that "holes are better carriers of valley information": because they live longer.